# Selecting rows based on multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, toad

I want to gather all the details from a table `PROD` about rows containing particular triplet-sets of values. For example, I want to get all the data on the rows having columns (`ID`, `NBR` AND `COP_I`) with values (23534, 99, 0232) and (3423,5,09384), etc. I tried Version 1, but it only gives me a couple of such rows when I know there needs to be 100 and Version 2 runs into an error. I wasn't able to think of any other way to do this.

Version 1:

```
SELECT * FROM PROD

WHERE 

ID IN (2534, 3423) 

AND NBR IN (99, 5)

AND COP_I IN (0232, 09384)
```

Version 2:

```
SELECT * FROM PROD

WHERE 

    (ID = '23534',  NBR ='99',  COP_I ='0232'),
AND (ID = '3423',   NBR ='5',   COP_I ='09384')
```

**Update**:

I currently get something like:

```
ID     NBR_IN   COP_I  FLAG  TYPE     DATE 
23534  99       0232   0     CATHAY   15-04-2017
```

And don't end up getting the (3423, 5, 09384) triplet's row. Basically, only some of the triplet's rows appear in the results and the results turn out to be the same as what I get from Version 1 above.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use an `OR` condition.

```
SELECT * FROM PROD
WHERE (ID = '23534' AND  NBR ='99' AND COP_I ='0232')
OR (ID = '3423' AND NBR ='5' AND COP_I ='09384')
```

Comment: I appear to get the same results as what I got when I used "Version 1" in my Question. Would you have an idea why this query isn't working?

Comment: some sample data and the expected result would help.

Comment: I added some sample data and explained further what my expected result is.

Answer (score 1):

Your second query was going along the right track except that you need to replace the `AND` with an `OR` and the `,`s with `AND`s.

```
SELECT * 
FROM PROD
WHERE 
    (ID = '23534' AND NBR ='99' AND COP_I = '0232')
OR 
    (ID = '3423' AND  NBR ='5' AND COP_I = '09384')
```

Comment: I am having the strangest issue wherein a lot of the rows corresponding to particular triplets are not showing up. Could you possibly think of why this may be?

Comment: @Jojo are you sure the data is what you think it is?

Comment: Im sorry, Im not too sure what you mean by this question.

Comment: @Jojo I'm asking if the table actually contains data that matches the query.  Looking at the update in your question, why do you expect a row with ID `2534` to be returned by a query looking for ID `3423`?

Comment: Im sorry, that was my bad whilst copying. I've updated this.

Comment: @Jojo I think you need to paste your full, actual query, because your results don't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify triplets like this:

```
SELECT * FROM PROD 
WHERE ( id, nbr, cop_i ) IN ( ('23534','99','0232'), ('3423','5','09384') );
```

Comment: Thanks, but this answer appears to throw up an error.

Comment: Hmmm.  I tried it in Oracle and it works fine.  What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM PROD AS p
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 23534 AS col1, 99 AS col2, 232 AS col3 UNION ALL
   SELECT 3423,          5,          9384
) AS t ON p.ID = t.col1 AND p.NBR = t.col2 AND p.COP_I = t.col3
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on how many pairs of values you may need to do this with, and your RDBMS, you could do something like this:

```
create table #tempThingy (ID int, NBR int, COP_I int)

insert into #tempThingy (id, nbr, cop_i) 
select 23534, 99, 0232
union all select 3423, 5, 09384

select   *
from prod p
inner join #tempThingy t on p.id = t.id
    and p.nbr = t.nbr
    and p.cop_i = t.cop_i
```